# Charterstone Resources going to next game

Tags: charterstone

When finishing each game of the campaign you have to discard the various bits and pieces you've collected down to a limit based on what's marked on your tuck box.

Specifically in relation to the actual resources (coal, brick etc), if I have a limit of 3 resources does each resource have to be different or can I keep 3 coal for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Capacity card, there are asterisks next to Advancement Cards and Minions that denote those must be of different types, but Resources and Coins are not limited in this way.  If you can keep three resources, all three of them can be coal; only the total number of Resources is limited.